# Repeat List Until Longer

Tags: code-golf, array

### The Challenge

The challenge is simple: given an input list `a` and another list `b`, repeat `a` until it is longer than `b`.

As an example, call the repeated list `ra`. Then the following condition must hold true: `len(b) < len(ra) <= len(b) + len(a)`. That is, `a` must not be repeated more than is required.

### Sample Python Implementation

```python
def repeat(a, b):
    ra = a.copy()
    while len(b) >= len(ra):
        ra += a
    return ra
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcxLCoNAEIThtZ6il9OkCCSaJ5iLiIvWdFCQcWgmBE8/UXFXi6/@MMd@8kVKb/2QaVCJTkAtP/PMhCqSYzeF2XGe/fphVBrVu5bpVW3LZIWrPCx0uWj8mieTFGzw0e3F@oQzigZUl7jgihvueDTM6Q8)

### Examples

```
[1,2,3], [2,4] -> [1,2,3]
[1,2,3], [2,3,4] -> [1,2,3,1,2,3]
[1,2,3], [18,26,43,86] -> [1,2,3,1,2,3]
[2,3,5], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] -> [2,3,5,2,3,5,2,3,5]
[1,123], [1,12,123,1234] -> [1,123,1,123,1,123]
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer in bytes wins. Have fun!

Comment: May we assume that the lists are filled with positive integers, as your examples suggest?

Comment: @Arnauld sure. Go for it

Answer (score 18):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 29 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:len(y)//len(x)*x+x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUaFCp9IqJzVPo1JTXx9EV2hqVWhX/P8PAA)

Answer (score 10):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
*¹→¤÷L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X@vQzkdtkw4tObzd5////9GGOoZGxrEQGsQEYZNYAA)

```
   ¤     # combin: ¤ f g x y = f (g x) (g y)
     L   #    where g = length
    ÷    #    and f = integer divide
         # so ¤÷L calculates the (integer) ratio of input lengths;
   →     # then increment the result,
 *¹      # and repeat input 1 that many times
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 7 bytes

```
₅?Lḭ›ẋf
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJyIiwiIiwi4oKFP0zhuK3igLrhuotmIiwiIiwiWzIsMyw1XVxuWzEsMiwzLDQsNSw2LDddIl0=)

**How it works:**

```
₅?Lḭ›ẋf    
₅        # Push first list and its length
 ?Lḭ     # Integer-divide by length of second list
    ›    # Increment ^
     ẋ   # Repeat first list that many times
      f  # Flatten into a single list
```

Answer (score 8):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```apl
{(A×⌈(⍴⍵,1)÷A←⍴⍺)⍴⍺}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@lR24RqDcfD0x/1dGg86t3yqHerjqHm4e2OQHEwd5cmhKr9/99QwUjBWCFJwRBImiiYKphxGQLZID4YcsHlLRSMzBRMjBUszLhAIqZgNSAWmATpMoKYY2gEZgKxCQA)

Thanks to [Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m) for golfing some bytes and helping me to fix errors in chat.
`⎕←,⍣2⍨'thanks'`

-2 thanks to [AZTECCO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84844/aztecco) `⎕←'thanks'`

Comment: This is only 22 bytes using [SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS).

Comment: [-2?](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/9/eNqjtgnVGo96twKRwqPeXZpADEQIka2atUByrkJAfk5lWmZOjkJafhFQYOn/JLBOx8PTH/V0AJVvASrVMdQ8vN0RKA7mgswCUbX//xsqGCkYKyQpGAJJEwVTBTMuQyAbxAdDLri8hYKRmYKJsYKFGRdIxBSsBsQCkyBdRhBzDI3ATCA2AQA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: Um, your TIO link says that this code is 42 bytes... did I miss something?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin this is SBCS see Adám comment above.

Comment: did you subtract the bytes for `b←` twice?

Comment: [15 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/P@lR24RHXYsf9W551LtCA8g6PN1Q@1FP16PeJYe3A4U0H/UuBUr@/2@oYKRgrJCkYAgkTRRMFcy4DIFsEB8MueDyFgpGZgomxgoWZlwgEVOwGhALTIJ0GUHMMTQCM4HYBAA) tacit

Comment: [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/P@lR2wSNR12LDk831H7U0/Wod8nh7ZqPepc@6t0CQl2L/v83VDBWMFEwVTBTSFIwVDBSMOYyVIBAEN@Qy9BCwchMwcRYwQJZBZCEsIFiINIUpMsIiIxB2ASi18gYAA) tacit with argument order reversed

Answer (score 7):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to [Jonah](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15469/jonah)'s very clever idea!*

```
];@;<.@%&##<@]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/Y60drG30HFTVlJVtHGL/a3L5OekpxKrUKTvEahkCJbSBMmAxINvOCqTO2kEFqJIrNTkjX8FIwUQhTcEQSBvDBIyxC5miChrChc0UzIFSIJ7pfwA)

Takes input as `b f a`, if `f` is the name you assign the verb to.

### Explanation

```
];@;<.@%&##<@]
       %          divide
        &#        the lengths of the lists by each other
    <.@           and floor it;
           <@]    box b
          #       and repeat it that many times
]  ;              prepend b to this boxed array
 ;@               and raze the result, collapsing it into a single list
```

Instead of incrementing the division result, as I did in the first version below, we simply prepend the input list to the resulting tiled box list, which is equivalent.

### Old Answer

```
]$~#@]*1<.@+%&#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6zkE6Pm7/Y1XqlB1itQxt9By0VdWU/2typSZn5CsYKZgo4ABpQGwIVGAMU2mMSy2aSkMLBSMzBRNjBQszQiqhppoqmCmYY6oESZrCVBoaAZExCJtgMxMojk0liDAlQSWYNEOo/A8A)

#### Explanation

```
]$~#@]*1<.@+%&#
            %      divide
             &#    the lengths of the lists by each other
       1   +       increment
        <.@        and floor
      *            multiplied by
   #@]             length of a
]$~                and reshape a to be that length
```

Unfortunately, `#` doesn't work here, as it doesn't preserve the order. (`1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 -: 3 # 1 2 3`.)

Comment: Managed to eke off one more byte: `];@;<.@%&##<@]`.  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/Y60drG30HFTVlJVtHGL/a3L5OekpxKrUKTvEahkCJbSBMmAxINvOCqTO2kEFqJIrNTkjX8FIwUQhTcEQSBvDBIyxC5miChrChc0UzIFSIJ7pfwA "J – Try It Online")

Comment: @Jonah Clever approach boxing the input! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

## Curry, <s>57</s> 42 bytes

This being my first Curry answer, I'm pretty certain its not quite optimal, but as it is our current lang of the month, I figured I'd give at least a half-hearted try at it.

```
l=length
a!b|l a>l b=a|1>0=a++a!drop(l a)b
```

Edit: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4tKqrULUjMTi7@/z/HNic1L70kgytRMakmRyHRLkchyTaxxtDOwDZRWztRMaUov0ADKK6Z9D83MTNPwVYh2kjHWMc0VkFRIdpQB8Q20THVMdMx17GI/Q8A)

A bit longer than I'd like, my first idea involved the recursive return being `r(a++a)b`, but I realized that didn't work unless the correct number of repetitions was a power of two.

Edit -15 bytes from some good tips by [WheatWizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard)

Comment: There are a couple of things you could apply here from the Haskell tips page.  [Replacing r with an infix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19259), and [replacing if with a guard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/24670/56656) would shorten things a bit.  These two together can get you down to [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##Sy4tKqrULUjMTi7@/z/HNic1L70kgytRMakmRyHRLkchyTaxxtDOwDZRWztRMaUov0ADKK6Z9D83MTNPwVYh2kjHWMc0VkFRIdpQB8Q20THVMdMx17GI/Q8A "Curry (PAKCS) – Try It Online").

Comment: ah good ones @WheatWizard! clearly theres a lot still to learn about this language

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/WheatWizard/haskell-golfing-library), 18 bytes

```
m**frt$P1<<fdv.*l
```

Divide the lengths, add 1 and then repeat that many times.

## Reflection

This is kind of long, but also pretty compact.  Part of the issue is that variable reuse is always going to be a bit long.  We also have to use both `frt` and `fdv` which are unfortunately 3 bytes each.  It's totally possible to do this without flipping via `rt` and `dv`

```
m jn$rt<<P1<<dv.*l
```

But that ends up being a byte longer.

It seems mostly like a quirk of the specific problem that flipping is required.

The only real improvement I can see here is to combine some of the glue used to make things more compact.

- `m jn` used in the 19 byte solution could be 1 function.  It has a useful type.  If it were 3 bytes it would save 1 byte overall

  ```
  mjn$rt<<P1<<dv.*l
  ```
- `l2 m` is a little more niche but could be added.  As a 3 byte prefix it would actually have *costed* a byte here

  ```
  l2m frt$P1<<fdv.*l
  ```

  It could also be an infix, but that also costs a byte.

  ```
  frt**<(P1<<fdv.*l)
  ```

  However in better circumstances it could potentially save a byte.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
gIg÷>и
```

Takes the input-lists in the order \$b,a\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/3TP98Ha7Czv@/4820jHWMYnlijbUAbJiAQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWWCS9H/9OL0w9vtLuz4r/M/OjraSMc4VifaUAdEx@oogAV0TFCFDC10jMx0TIx1LMzQJHTAqnVMdcx0zIFSIJ4pTMrQCIiMQRhiHJARGxsLAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
g       # Push the length of the first (implicit) input-list `b`
 Ig     # Push the length of the second input-list `a`
   ÷    # Integer-divide the length by `b` by that of `a`
    >   # Increase it by 1
     и  # Repeat the second (implicit) input-list `a` that many times
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ẋɓL:L}‘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hru6Tk32sfGofNcz4f3i5/tFJD3fO0Iz8/z862lDHSMc4Vkch2kjHJBZEI4sYY4gZWugYmemYGOtYmEFkQIpMwTI6YPU6pjpmOuYwXYZGEF1ABogNwkATAQ)

Nothing all too original.

```
ẋ          Repeat a by
 ɓL        the length of b
   :L}     floor divided by the length of a
      ‘    plus 1.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <sup><s>10</s></sup> 9 bytes

```
*h/l.).Ql
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/XytDP0dPUy8w5///aCMdYx3TWK5oQx0Qy0THVMdMxzwWAA)

```
*h/l.).Ql

   l.).Q    # get the length of the second list
  /     l   # integer divide it by the length of the first list
 h          # increment the result of the division
*           # multiply by the first list (like int * list in Python)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 29 bytes

```perl
sub{(@{$a=shift})x(1+@_/@$a)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBNS8MwGMfP5lM8hGgbfET66liJ5i64y261jEaTOtS1thUmpZ@9Jt0ERVgO4f/2uzyNbt@SiRkxdZ9q8OXAStG9bE0/8r0fXMrNtWQlH6eMmLr1SQ725QGGGBUIeYhxAeL2J7Fdgf830Z8VntgGCwxTjCNcpKcJlyYzMQ9iTDDFmwMzd/jrP5J8II59//JZiUwh01xItsmOqazEBTOuk0zxQ9q0211v6PlV2llXLsEewwrlhLJC7xv91Otn57X1Vd1bWT3uKJIzajMK@gOorCjcgVe/erAE72G1htW9l5Fx@gY)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 43 bytes

Expects `(a)(b)`. This code assumes that both lists are filled with positive integers (as allowed by the OP).

```javascript
a=>g=(b,...c)=>c[b.length]?c:g(b,...c,...a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hctNDsIgEIbhvafoEpKRpoViY0I9CGFBkaINKcY2Xh8DNv4sTGfxbd55Rv3Qs7lfb8t@CmcbBxG16JxAPRBCDBadkT3xdnLLRZ3M0a0hjcbRhGkO3hIfHBqQrKAGqjCSNTCFcfG5sizWuvtv6K96G9iQVQs1B0ah5S@/JVNpssxPDBrgcEg2yVzha1V8Ag)

Comment: Really clever, but it looks like it fails eg on `f([0,0,0])([18,26,43,86]))`.

Comment: @Jonah I assumed the lists were filled with positive integers, but this is indeed not specified. I've asked the OP to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 18 bytes

```
{(~(#y)<#:)(x,)/x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxtT0FugzAQvPsVK6UHLBksbONQXPUVuSFLQRQSFAopOBIoSt5e7NKEJj3seHZmNCuXydm7eqsRv60S7A0E0+GC0CY5v6TjtUtKCGBQ2/agvG2ZVbUa1Kg6rC9ok3ohMOCKgcDKUb0U+U2GRzOMgUkQHGL5HLFbNKsCIpCwxq4uggXObSGb2ia0xI476fgdNUIU7Y059gmleftR7Nq6DHqT5YdiyPdZsyuCvP2kX6eiN1Xb9JQJ/hrFtCuORWb8uuqNf2pMVft1O4U7hNKQMMI1pIwIDf47zMLS4H8s8hgIY8IkEZzE8r+Y5ZH+VQWJiCTrn6CzyAJdq/0ouNdSO7fzbr+jRt+7lHTR)

Appends copies of `x` until the length is greater than the length of `y`.

- `(cond)(code)/x` set up a while-reduce, beginning with `x`, the input. the "code" part is repeated until the "cond" part returns a non-truthy value

  - `(~(#y)<#:)` check whether or not the current list is longer than `y`
  - `(x,)` prepend a copy to the current list

An alternative version, with the same byte count, instead uses the do-reduce overload, swapping `(~(#y)<#:)` for `((-#x)!#y)`.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```r
\(a,b,`-`=length)rep(a,1+-b/-a)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGSNAUb3aWlJWm6FvtjNBJ1knQSdBNsc1Lz0ksyNItSC4BChtq6Sfq6iZoQVTfj0zSSNQx1jHSMNXWSNYx0TDQ1udCEjDEFDS10jMx0TIx1LMygUiBlpmApHbAOHVMdMx1zTag1CxZAaAA)

-2 bytes thanks to pajonk.

Comment: Why the integer division? Standard `/` seems fine: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcvLDkAwFIThvSfpiWmkF2XBu6BpkUiJ1PPXJVZsv39mT77hyR/BxnkNrMeAjnft4sIYJ9rddpHI@VDwnpJnlglIKIJlEpoo@5D6o6ghDbRCbd50z8on4XmghEFFlE4 "R – Try It Online") *(I don't know why ATO doesn't work for me...)*.

Comment: @pajonk because I didn't think to try it! Thanks! Have you tried asking in the ATO chatroom? Maybe they could offer you help.

Comment: I did, it was a known temporary problem.

Answer (score 4):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>55</s> 49 bytes

```
f(a,b)=[lforl=a,i=[0...floor(b.length/a.length)]]
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/b8wdtegkqi)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bemfawamsu)

<s>I had to write `l=a[1...]` instead of just `l=a` because apparently Desmos defaults to recognizing function arguments as numbers, which the list comprehension doesn't like. The workaround is to force Desmos to recognize it as a list by slicing it in such a way that it just returns the entire list, resulting in +6 bytes.</s>

Apparently the workaround wasn't even necessary because I *think* `a.length` forces Desmos to recognize `a` as a list, rather than a number. Thanks [@att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att) for helping me realize this.

Comment: It still seems to work when I delete the `[1...]`... am I missing something?

Comment: @att bruh I swear it wasn't working when I [tested it](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kfreh552fw), that's wierd...

Comment: wait it might be because I put `a.length`, which forced desmos to recognize it as a list. dang, let me remove that right now.

Answer (score 4):

## [Exceptionally](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Exceptionally), <s>25</s> 18 bytes

```
GV}lL}nGVL/nIU*lP/
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m702tSI5taAkMz8vMSencsGCpaUlaboWm9zDanN8avPcw3z08zxDtXIC9CESUPkF26MNdQyNjGO5wDSICcImsRBpAA)

#### Explanation

```
' Get an input
G
' Eval it
V
' Store that in ls
} ls
' Get its length
L
' Store that in num
} num
' Get an input
G
' Eval it
V
' Get the length
L
' Divide by num
/ num
' Truncate to integer
I
' Increment
U
' Repeat ls that many times
* ls
' Print
P
' Attempt to divide the list by itself, ending the program
/
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `sequences.repeating`, <s>45</s> 42 bytes

```
[ length over length tuck /i 1 + * cycle ]
```

[image]

### Explanation

```
          ! { 2 3 5 } { 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 }
length    ! { 2 3 5 } 7
over      ! { 2 3 5 } 7 { 2 3 5 }
length    ! { 2 3 5 } 7 3
tuck      ! { 2 3 5 } 3 7 3
/i        ! { 2 3 5 } 3 2
1         ! { 2 3 5 } 3 2 1
+         ! { 2 3 5 } 3 3
*         ! { 2 3 5 } 9
cycle     ! { 2 3 5 2 3 5 2 3 5 }
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to [Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334/unrelated-string) in chat*

```
lᵐ÷<;?tᵗj₍
```

Takes input as a single list containing the two input lists in reverse order. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/P@fh1gmHt9tY25c83Do961FT7///0dGGOkY6xjomOqY6ZrE6ChBubOx/HwA)

#### Explanation

Ports the common strategy of using int-division to calculate the rep-count:

```
lᵐ÷<;?tᵗj₍
lᵐ          Length of each list in the input
  ÷         Int-divide
   <        Next greater integer
    ;?      Pair with input
      tᵗ    Replace the last element with its tail (i.e. the second input list)
        j₍  Repeat the last element a number of times equal to the first element
```

For example, with input `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [8, 9]]`:

```
lᵐ          [5, 2]
  ÷         2
   <        3
    ;?      [3, [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [8, 9]]]
      tᵗ    [3, [8, 9]]
        j₍  [8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9]
```

#### Old solution, 11 bytes

Implements the spec pretty directly, using Brachylog's backtracking:

```
hj↙İ.&tl<~l
h            The first of the inputs
 j           Concatenated to itself
  ↙İ         an unspecified number of times
    .        is the output
     &       And
      t      The second of the inputs
       l     Length of ^
        <    is less than a number
         ~l  which is the length of
             the output (implicit)
```

Comment: Nice call on using `İ`! I had 14 bytes before forgetting about it because (alongside not having thought of your trailing `~l`) arrow subscripting with a completely unconstrained variable does some [very strange things](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wPyPrUdvMCD21khybupz//6Ojow11jHSMY3UUoo10TGJBNLKIMYaYoYWOkZmOibGOhRlEBqTIFCyjA1avY6pjpmMO02VoBNEFZIDYIAw0MRYA) with explicit writes (although it's fine with "normal" I/O, oddly enough).

Answer (score 4):

## [Mathematica/Wolfram Language](https://wolfram.com/language), (44) 41 Bytes

`PadLeft[#,Ceiling[Tr[1^#2]+1,Tr[1^#]],#]&`

*-3 bytes from alephalpha on something I really should have caught*

I feel like this could still be shorter, but it works as-is. Uses Tr[1^x] as a way of getting Length for cheap, and takes advantage of Ceiling having a two-argument mode. Other than that, it would probably take a full rewrite to improve, since I can't use [LeftCeiling] to shave bytes with the two-argument mode.

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7PyAxxSc1rSRaWcc5NTMnMy89OqQo2jBO2ShW21AHwoyN1VGOVfufX1pimxZdbahjpGNcq1MNJHVMamO5Aooy80qigZKx/wE)

Comment: `#1` -> `#` saves 3 bytes.

Comment: How did I not catch that?

Comment: `Ceiling[a+1,b]` -> `Floor[a,b]+1`. Interestingly, two-argument `⌈a,b⌉` (and `⌊a,b⌋`) *does* work in wolframscript, but not in notebooks. Also, your tio link seems to be wrong.

Comment: The two actually seem to perform differently. Floor[1,2]+1 is equal to 1, while Ceiling is equal to 2. Fixing the TIO link now.

Comment: `Floor[1,2]+1` is 1. `Ceiling[1+1,2]` is also 1.

Comment: When I run Ceiling[2,2] in my Mathematica install, I get 2. TIO.run seems to agree.

Comment: https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvxKHaLSc/vyjaUMcoVttQxzk1MyczLz3aUBskUPv/PwA

Comment: Ah, you're right. I was thinking of the floor/ceil of the quotient; my bad.

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 33 bytes

```
Table[##&@@#,Tr[1^#2]/Tr[1^#]+1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7PyQxKSc1WllZzcFBWSekKNowTtkoVh/CiNU2jFX7H1CUmVcSraxrlwZUEqtWF5ycmFdXzVVtqGOkY1xbU22kY1Krg8w1RhUwtNAxMtMxMdaxMAMJg@RNQcI6YJU6pjpmOuYQ9YZGYPVAGsQEYZNartr/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
Ｗ¬›ⅉＬηＩθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/788IzMnVUHDL79Ew70oNbEktUgjUkNTR8EnNS@9JEMjQxMIFAKKMvNKNJwTi0s0CjU1rf//j4421DE0Mo7VAdMgJgibxMb@1y3LAQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｗ¬›ⅉＬη
```

Until the number of output lines exceeds the length of the second input...

```
Ｉθ
```

... output each element of the first input on its own line.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 26 bytes

```
->x,y{x*(y.size/x.size+1)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVBLToRAEI3bPkVlNg1MgeEzIzHDuHK2useOQQOxExRCwwQETuKGGL2ER_E0Ng2Oo3HR9arqvapKv5e3orprhtckeK_KxPQ_zG2NTVsbWmMJ_hyf1gqWtt5Pgs-TfRmLUkAAm83l1c4SecpLbXHztNCtxyhvu7oLazTqmaBgboHqrJ_IAjlmXSjhwNNpLt5HKdzaPY6JlskJEtrooMsgdNBj4565cUy4vyj8K7B9dNboueiv_5ON-Yp9dz1c4RrPJqGi8Ciqrbajtkoc0_Edzqv6JzIi3SFEmWXF0f0DtCC_Dxwh6whAXkkTtSQ0OIMggAwugF5HQlA4B7qLeEp1WAKVhYSCzPYPw4Rf)

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, 26 bytes

```
Prompt A,B
ʟA
While dim(Ans)≤dim(ʟB
augment(Ans,ʟA
End
Ans
```

Output is stored in `Ans` and displayed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 31 bytes

```julia
~=length
A%B=repeat(A,~B÷~A+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v842JzUvvSSDy1HVybYotSA1sUTDUafO6fD2OkdtQ83/XA7FGfnlCtGGOkY6xrEKqgrRRjomsQq2tjAhbAqMUZTo4FJoaKFjZKZjYqxjYYZbOUjEFKIcLGuiY6pjpmMO0QCW1EEikWwxNILaAmSBOCAMdxaYjyBj/wMA)

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, 18 bytes

Prompts for a nested vector comprising of list b followed by list a

```
∊(∊1+⌊÷/⍴¨v)⍴1↓v←⎕
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog APL Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3t/6OOLg0gNtR@1NN1eLv@o94th1aUaQIpw0dtk8uA6oDqgYrauf6ncWkYKZhoKmgYKhgpGGtygfnGaCKGFgpGZgomxgoWZqjiCmC1CqYKZgrmQBkQzxQqY2gERMYgDDELyNAEAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 61 bytes

```javascript
(a,b)=>Array(~~(b.length/a.length)+1).fill``.map(_=>a).flat()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY3NCoJAEIDvPUXHWZo2dv1JiBV6DpEcTc3YdkUl6OKrb2odpQ4DHzMf39zpSX3RNe2wN/Zauko5IMyZis9dRy8YR8i5Lk093A70BbYTjFeN1lnGH9TCRcU0LTQNwNxpU1jTW11ybWuoIBEo0Utxm0j0U8Z@3b0/hohQhuh7GIVr3hwIFg@XFgYY4nG9KOSnOMHM8yy/3Rs)

Way longer than the other answers but who cares. Should work in the browser too but TIO only supports `Array.flat()` in Node.

Comment: `~~(...)` => `...|0`, `.fill(a).flat()`

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 34 bytes

```perl6
{|@^a xx 1+@^b.elems div@^a.elems}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7dCoIwFL73Kc5VKJ2CbbqEKHwPmWA0IVCIhFCqZ1/bUWnGLnZ2zvfHd9ePVppuhE0DJ/N6F1UNwwBsW1SXvW5118P19rTodHzMMerrEZo4ZshRJBhzTJMkgIogznLkElOBufRYp84ci@TDDCUeVm7GyW1/t7pH6aYki4LS1lCwO8MMRB4hVhT@C7xKIRl1Uws6d5uERKE3KdV2I7lXdcml@zfVFw)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>62</s> 61 bytes

*-1 thanks to @ceilingcat*

```c
f(*a,b,c,d){for(;b=++d%c;);for(;d--;)printf("%d ",a[b++%c]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/LCoMwEEX3/YoiCEm9LvLSQvBLbBeZiKXQ2lK6E7/dRlPdiItZ3BPumYnP/cN1t3Fs2cmB4NHwvn19mKUqy5rUW27n2OS55e/Pvfu2LEmbYwJXU5al/srtMD7dvWO8P4TnoxP1teoFJNRgZ0IzkdAht8wJkICC5PawCC9dElKsy01dxrpaBBI0JbUjUBtBJGfIAlrhXESNAqlJuqPRy1azaPQqhoZBgTKKNEgHVu6ITKwJud6zkglO8/@YAZmg3140jD8) Inputs are list `a`, list `b`, and their respective lengths in that order (as C doesn't store length information in arrays); outputs are sent to stdout.

Comment: [54](https://tio.run/##dc9NCsIwEAXgvaeQQiHRJ5i/Wog9ibrIpFQErSLuas9e08Z2U7rIYl54XyZ@5@@uvnZdxTYOBI@SN9XzzajYWzoW5ZdSb/nrfas/FUvScp3AnWi7Tf2F27Z7uFvNeLMK12snTpeiEZBQrR0SGhIJHeaKOQESUJDcrkbwXCdhinU5q8tYVyMgQf2kFgA1A2KSQ2bQCnkWGQVSPbrA6PFVMzJ6gqFhkOEQIQ3SITssQCbWhJz2mZI@7M//YwZkAj/fqO1@)

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 17 bytes

```
⊑⥊˜≠∘⊑×1+·⌊∘÷˜´≠¨
```

Anonymous tacit function that takes a single argument, a list containing the two input lists. [Try it at BQN online](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RyDihpAg4oqR4qWKy5ziiaDiiJjiipHDlzErwrfijIriiJjDt8ucwrTiiaDCqAoKRyDin6gy4oC/MywgMeKAvzLigL8z4oC/NOKAvzXin6kKCg==)

#### Explanation

```
⊑⥊˜≠∘⊑×1+·⌊∘÷˜´≠¨
                ≠¨  Length of each list
               ´    Fold that two-integer list on
              ˜     Reversed-order
           ⌊∘÷      Division-and-floor
          ·         Then
        1+          Add 1
       ×            Multiply by
    ≠∘⊑             Length of the first list
 ⥊˜                Reshape to that length
⊑                  The first list
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 12 bytes

```
Ty#>b{Yy.a}y
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJUeSM+YntZeS5hfXkiLCIiLCIiLCJcIjFcIlwiMlwiXCIzXCIgXCIxXCJcIjJcIlwiM1wiXCI0XCIiXQ==)

How?

```
Ty#>b{Yy.a}y
T    {    }  - Till
 y#>b        - Length of y greater than length of b(2nd input)
      Y        - Yank (equivalent to (y:a))
       y.a     - y concatenated with a
           y - Return y
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 10 \log_{256}(96) \approx\$ 8.23 bytes

```
LsL|1+z0A*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuharfIp9agy1qwwctSACUPEF26ONdIx1TGO5og11QCwTHVMdMx3zWIg0AA)

**Explanation:**

```python
LsL|1+z0A*  # Implicit input
LsL         # Length of both lists
   |1+      # Integer divided and incremented
      z0    # Push the first list
        A*  # Repeat that many times
            # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 8 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
▽+1⌊÷∩⧻,
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4pa9KzHijIrDt-KIqeKnuywKCmYgWzIgNF0gWzEgMiAzXQpmIFsyIDMgNF0gWzEgMiAzXQpmIFsxOCAyNiA0MyA4Nl0gWzEgMiAzXQpmIFsxIDIgMyA0IDUgNiA3XSBbMiAzIDVdCmYgWzEgMTIgMTIzIDEyMzRdIFsxIDEyM10=)

```
▽+1⌊÷∩⧻,
       ,  # over
     ∩⧻   # length of both
    ÷     # divide
   ⌊      # floor
 +1       # increment
▽         # keep
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>43</s> 48 bytes

+5 bytes, realised it doesn't work

```javascript
a=>b=>{for(A=[...a];!a[b.length];a.push(...A));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9NboMwEEb3nGK6wpYmlvgJjYRAyqKnoJYyUAiuHIyAZhPl7NQmDUmrLjwe@3vzLH/SmcZqUP206cxHPTfZTFleZvmlMQPbZ4UQgmT6QkUpdN0dp1amJPqvsWU22XOeXueDVwQYYiShCDGWsMnh5@I5iH5F@BcIdhgmGEe4S/7DXL@V99sYt5jg6w1cInyqizUIF6vdXevW@vxyflTpHcQ0qBPjYuy1mpj/3vlc2P@/UdUyrboashwuHkBlunGCQiEYCRm46D7j3D5PHxAhlA5SK2GlJ@pZfSa9gA0jzsp1xuhaaHNk1n6zIZANr3z@Bg)

An alternative JS answer. Takes curried input `a` and `b` and extends `a` until it's longer than `b`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 33 bytes

```
$[a,b][repeat a 1+/size b size a]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?V9nMJT)

Integer divide the length of b by the length of a, add one, and repeat a that many times.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
,ḷẸ÷⁺ọ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#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)

##### Explanation

```python
,ḷẸ÷⁺ọ  # Implicit input
,ḷ      # Length of both
  Ẹ÷    # Floor divide
    ⁺   # Increment
     ọ  # Repeat first list
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 42 bytes

```javascript
a=>b=>b.flatMap((_,i)=>~i%a.length*i?[]:a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDLbsMgEEX3/orZVIZqguRH3KiR3VWX/QIXNWPXTqiIsWyUTdX@ugtO82hUCYaBezhIfNCBxnpQvV105r2Z2nyivKjcEK0m@0I9Y2@oeF58qzsSuum2dnevnkr5SHxab4IywhgTCWWMqYRFAb8H10HyJ8JbIFphnGGa4Cr7D/P9Up5OU1xihg9HcI7wqs7WKJ6tbvWtn@fn5/2lymAj7KD2jIux18qy8LULuWjN8Ez1jmnVNZAX8BkA1KYbLZQKwUjIwUenO94d8vUFIoTKQ@pMOOnefWVzIH0GjW6ENlvmlEcFQsuIs4o75ItPPw)

Assumes `len(a)>1`

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 46 bytes

```javascript
a=>b=>[...b,a].flatMap((_,i)=>i%a.length?a:[])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNboMwEEb3nGI2FbY0scRPaNTIdNVlT0CtZqCQuHIwAiubqmenmDQkrbLweDzf87PkTzrRUPW6c6vWftRjI0eSeSnzQghRIinRGHKv1DH2jprLXD@QMHW7d4dneioUH7e7oIgwxkRBEWOqYJXD7@A2SP5E@B@INhhnmCa4ye5hvl@ryzTFNWb4eAbnCG/qbI3i2TrtvvVreX4@X6sKdsL1@si4GDqjHQvf2pCLxvYvVB2Y0W0NMoevAKCy7eCg0AhWgQQfXe54d8i3V4gQSg/phZikx@kf6xOZBbSmFsbu2aQ8KxAaRpyVfEK@@fgD)